# How to build vue.js for subfolder

Tags: vue.js, iis, build

I have deployed vue js application in IIS in default website but it's not loading assets due to it is deployed in a sub folder of default website . Kindly help me to set recommended configuration to resolve this issue.

#### Screenshots are available here:

[image: Errors]

#### Figure 1: Errors

[image: Site Basic Setting]

#### Figure 2: Site Basic Setting

[image: Site Advance Setting]

#### Figure 3: Site Advance Setting

[image: Folder Structure]

#### Figure 4: Folder Structure

Comment: did you try to put the <base href="/b2c/"> in your index file? could you share your iis app setting and folder structure?

Comment: please refer this link for more detail:https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/deployment.html#surge

Comment: @JalpaPanchal : <base href="/b2c/"> is also not working screenshots are now available is question.

Comment: to run vue application in iis you need to build first. by using command prompt enter to the vue folder and run this command `npm run build
` which creates the dist folder under your site folder. use this folder as the iis folder path.

Comment: @Jalpa Panchal yes it is the build , not source code !

Comment: is your issue resolved?

Comment: @jalpaPanchal , I don't want to change my website after building ... I am finding some solution to add some configuration in VUE.JS application so after build i will be able to deploy as is.... till now NO success.

Comment: if you do not want to change the link of the CSS and js file you could directly add this folder as a site in iis. in my opinion, this is the only other way.

Answer (score 0):

first, apply the iis_iusrs and iusr full control permission to the site folder.

then open your index.html file and set the format of all the CSS and js file links shown as below :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang=en>
<head>
<meta charset=utf-8>
<meta http-equiv=X-UA-Compatible content="IE=edge">
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">

<link rel=icon href=favicon.ico><title>my-vueapp</title>
<link href=css/app.7fafd6a0.css rel=preload as=style>
<link href=js/app.3ddf6310.js rel=preload as=script>
<link href=js/chunk-vendors.763c0f03.js rel=preload as=script>
<link href=css/app.7fafd6a0.css rel=stylesheet>

</head>

<body>
<noscript>
<strong>We're sorry but my-vueapp doesn't work properly without JavaScript enabled. Please enable it to continue.</strong>
</noscript><div id=app></div>
<script src=js/chunk-vendors.763c0f03.js></script>
<script src=js/app.3ddf6310.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and another is you also need to set the link for the logo so find the appropriate js file and also change the link of the logo:

[image]

below is my iis site setting:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]